# point subdomain from website-1 to subfolder on website-2 (both hosted on the same server)

Tags: hosting, subdomain, cpanel

I have a client with three websites, each with separate c-panels for their hosting and dns management.

I need to point a subdomain from website-1 and website-2 to website-3, and then have their root be a subfolder on website-3.

I was able to set up a simple subdomain for website-3, and set it's root to the subfolder that I needed, but am having trouble pointing the other two sites.

It seems (from googling around) that the issue is caused by the site's all sharing an IP address, since they're all on the same server.

On website-3 where the subfolder is, I've tried setting up an "add-on domain" of test.website-1.com but get an error stating:

```
website-1.com is already configured. Sorry, that domain is already setup (remove it from httpd.conf)
```

I get a similar error trying to use the park a domain settings in the cpanel. I don't have access to the server in a way that lets me httpd.conf (unless there's a way through the cpanel).

Is there any other way to set this up that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, you can create a website (Add Web site under Sites folder in IIS) in IIS and point to any folder.  For example, if you are trying to point a subdomain mysubdomain.website-1.com to a particular folder, create a website in IIS that points to that subfolder, then in bindings, bind it to mysubdomain.website-1.com. In your domain registry, simply point the sub domain to the same IP of Website-1.  I believe that should work.

Unfortunately, my knowledge is limited to IIS. If you are not using IIS, you may find other resources to configure a subdomain.

Comment: They're on linux hosting, so this won't help, but thank you for the suggestion. I think we'll need to move the one site to a different server so that the IP addresses are different.

Answer (score 0):

If all your primary domains are using same IP , you will not be able to point the subdomains as you have mentioned since all the subdomains also using the same IPs.

Instead of pointing the subdomain 1 subdomain 2 to subdomain 3 ... just set up redirects directly to subdomain 3 for each subdomain from their primary domain's cpanel.

You can easily set the redirects from Redirects option in cpanel